# use 2 functions or only one function if both function have the same set of parameters?

Tags: clojure

To make the code more readable, there are some suggestion that one function should do simple thing and then compose functions into a big one. But if small function could accept the same multiple set of parameter, if use multiple function, then the parameters are duplicated, in this case how to write a more readable code?

e.g in the following 2 functions, fun1 and fun2 has the same set of parameters, both could accept only one parameter, or could acceptable 2 parameters. If use one function (copy the code from fun2 to fun1), then I don't duplicate the parameters set (one for a parameter and another for 2 parameters). Is there better approaches?

```
(defn fun1
  ([x] (fun1 x nil))
  ([x y] (do ....
         (fun2 x y)))
  )

(defn fun2
  ([x] (fun2 x nil))
  ([x y] (......))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use one function, you have to check the values of arguments because the bodies of the functions are different. I think it will make your code less clear and more  difficult to follow and, if possible at all, test. A little duplication in code sometimes is acceptable, therefore if I were you I'd keep 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
(comp do-something-to fun2)
```

... has all the arities of `fun2`. Whether you give this phrase a name ...

```
(def fun1 (comp do-something-to fun2))
```

... is moot.

---

I'm assuming your `fun1` is like ...

```
(defn fun1
  ([x] (fun1 x nil))
  ([x y] (do-something-to
         (fun2 x y)))
  )
```

The `do` you have will not affect the returned value.

By the way, you'll need to `(declare fun2)` first if you want to define `fun1` ahead of `fun2`.